# How to reference a polymer component from auto-binding template?

Tags: polymer

How to reference the `ts` component from a binding annotation in an auto-binding template, as in `{{ts.value}}` shown below:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
    <tri-state id='ts' value="open"></tri-state>
    Value: {{ts.value}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to do this. Just imagine that the auto-binding template has a property called x (for example) and bind both things to x like this:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
    <tri-state value="{{x}}"></tri-state>
    Value: {{x}}
</template>
```